# ClassNotFound: Xerces SAXParserFactoryImpl when running in Wildfly 8.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, ear, xerces

I am running Wildfly 8.2.0 and doing some XML Config file parsing. The idea is that I'll be able to use my bundled xercesImpl.jar to provide the JAXP SAXParserFactoryImpl.

When running the logic outside of Wildfly, I am successfully able to parse with the SAXParserFactoryImpl. This factory is found by setting the system property:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory",
                   "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
SAXParserFactory factory = javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
```

After deploying my EAR, I receive the following error:

```
...: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found.
..
..
...: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl
..
..
```

Knowing that Wildfly runs its own Xerces from wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xerces/main/xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas2.jar, I have tried the following:

**[1] Use Wildfly's xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas2.jar ... no change**

*(Source: Wildfly Documentation for jboss-deployment-structure.xml)*

In jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        ...
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

EARContent:

```
lib/
    ...(removed xercesImpl.jar)...
META-INF/
    application.xml // Information about EJB that uses xercesImpl.jar
    jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

**[2] Ignore Wildfly's xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas2.jar ... no change**

*(Source: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/259010?start=0&tstart=0)*

In jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
        </exclusions>
        ...
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

EARContent:

```
lib/
    xercesImpl.jar
    ...(many more jars)...
META-INF/
    application.xml // Information about EJB that uses xercesImpl.jar
    jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

**[3] Explicitly include Wildfly's xerces as a module ... no change**

*(Source: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239969)*

In jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>  
              <module name="org.apache.xerces" /> 
              ...
        </dependencies>  
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

EARContent:

```
lib/
    ...(removed xercesImpl.jar)...
META-INF/
    application.xml // Information about EJB that uses xercesImpl.jar
    jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

**[4] Declare Java property for JAXP Parser ... no change**

when launching Wildfly:

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

in standalone-full.xml

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory" value="org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"/>
</system-properties>
```

(Note: Tried this property with attempts [1], [2], [3])

**[5] Adding Xerces Path to jboss-deployment-structure ... no change**

*(Source: developer.jboss.org/message/717927#717927)*

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system>
                <paths>
                    <path name="org/apache/xerces/jaxp"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try variant 3 but add export="true" to dependency

I suppose you try use javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance() from ejb or war. Subdeployments don't see dependency modules of ear. You must do export explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that the classloader of the thread containing the EJB that tried to load SAXParserFactoryImpl did not have access to it. To remedy this, I had to find a thread that had a classloader with SAXParserFactoryImpl visibility (happened to be on my MDB) and manually set it on the problematic bean. I never did determine just what was happening, but this was a quick and dirty work around.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of RND finally found the solution.
Here  is goes :

1) Copy your XercesImpl-X.x.x.jar and paste it in the /jre/lib/
   eg:- for me --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib
2) Inside the lib create a new folder "endorsed".
3) Paste the jar file inside the "**endorsed**" folder
4) Restart the server and the xerces hell is subsides.

Let me know if the solution worked for you.